# difference between Metatrader CSV and C# StreamWriter CSV. How to solve it?

Tags: c#, csv, metatrader4

I have a Code in Metatrader that writes some Quotes to CSV, but while doing same in C# the Expert advisor reads the values a different way....
This Code in MetaEditor writes the CSV file:

```
li_40 = FileOpen(ls_32, FILE_CSV|FILE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_READ, ";");
      if (li_40 > 0) {
         FileWrite(li_40, ls_16);
         FileClose(li_40);
```

This Writes in C#:

```
            List<string> listB = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(oFile)))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    listB.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            using (StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(oFile))
            {

                foreach (var item in listB)
                {
                    swOut.Write(item);
                    swOut.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        swOut.Write(", ");
                    }

                    value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                    string vals = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                                           int priceDecimalPlaces = vals.Split('.').Count() > 1
                                  ? vals.Split('.').ToList().ElementAt(1).Length
                                  : 0;
                                            string nell = "0";
                                            if (priceDecimalPlaces == 3)
                                            {
                                                nell = "0.001";
                                            }
                                            if (priceDecimalPlaces == 5)
                                            {
                                                nell = "0.00001";
                                            }
                                            if (priceDecimalPlaces == 4)
                                            {
                                                nell = "0.0001";
                                            }

                    //replace comma's with spaces
                    value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                    //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                    value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

If the difference between the C# `double` and the Metatrader's current `double` value is `0.12098-0.12096=2`, the Metatrader won't  see the value as 2 but something very much higher like 18,17 and so on, but writing this same value from the MetaTrader's code gives correct value...

I read the CSV using _lread:

```
     uchar chBuff[1024];
     int res = _lread(hFile, chBuff, 1);
     //
     //CreateFileA(
     res = _lread(hFile, chBuff, 350);
     ls_308 = CharArrayToString(chBuff, 0, res, CP_UTF8);
  //Alert(Ls_84);
     ls_308=StringSubstr(ls_308,0,StringFind(ls_308,"\r\n",0));   

     if (_lclose(hFile)<0) Print("Error closing");
```

I think there are some difference between C# doubles on Metatrader and normal Metatrader doubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by the System's encoding language which was different to UTF-8 that was specified in the Metatrader code

```
ls_308 = CharArrayToString(chBuff, 0, res, CP_UTF8);
```

So, I changed the UTF to All Code Page assigned by System by doing this

```
ls_308 = CharArrayToString(chBuff, 0, res, CP_ACP);
```

Hope someone find this useful..